# does enabling fastboot in bios affect windows8 fastboot perfomance?

Tags: windows-8, bios

I have a hp probook 4540s laptop which has a fastboot option in bios. But I have heard that it reduces many tests done when booting up.

From my understanding win8 needs a bios test to check whether hardware changed, so that it can perform a fastboot if hardware hasn't changed.

Will windows be unable to use fastboot if i enable bios fastboot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fastBoot in BIOS means activating `Graphics Output Protocol` of [UEFI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface#Graphics_features) which speeds up boot because the old VGA is no longer used. I can change this setting without having issues to boot Windows 8. If you try to dualoot with Windows 7, disable it again.

Comment: Interesting, can you explain (even short) why diable it for windows 7?

Comment: @Psycogeek Windows 7 simply doesn't support GOP and hangs at the boot logo.